# What is NUXT Warning "Emitted value instead of an instance of Error" about?

Tags: javascript, debugging, vue.js, warnings, nuxt.js

I got this compiling warnings after applying [this NUXT tutorial](https://nuxtjs.org/examples/global-css) for adding Bulma as Global CSS:

> > nuxt-starter@1.0.0 dev /home/lsoave/Vue/nuxt-starter
> >     nuxt
>
> nuxt:build App root: /home/lsoave/Vue/nuxt-starter +0ms   nuxt:build
>   Generating /home/lsoave/Vue/nuxt-starter/.nuxt files... +2ms
>   nuxt:build Generating files... +8ms   nuxt:build Generating routes...
>   +13ms   nuxt:build Building files... +31ms   nuxt:build Adding webpack middleware... +688ms   ████████████████████ 100%
>
> Build completed in 5.51s
>
> WARNING  Compiled with 14 warnings
>   13:30:56
>
> warning  in ./node_modules/bulma/css/bulma.css
>
> (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error)
>   postcss-custom-properties:
>   /home/lsoave/Vue/sass/grid/columns.sass:469:4: Custom property
>   ignored: not scoped to the top-level :root element
>   (.columns.is-variable { ... --columnGap: ... })
>
> @ ./node_modules/bulma/css/bulma.css 4:14-118 13:3-17:5 14:22-126
>    @ ./.nuxt/App.js  @ ./.nuxt/index.js
>    @ ./.nuxt/client.js
>    @ multi webpack-hot-middleware/client?name=client&reload=true&timeout=30000&path=/__webpack_hmr ./.nuxt/client.js
>
> ...

Does anybody know why and how to get rid of those ?

Comment: Hi Luca, did you see [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1670)? It seems you could get rid of the warning by editing the `nuxt.config.js` with the following: `build: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: {
        'postcss-custom-properties': false
      }
    }
  }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @P3trur0 stated in the comment, you should add the following to `nuxt.config.js`:

```
  /*
  ** Build configuration
  */
  build: {
    ...,
    postcss: {
      plugins: {
        "postcss-custom-properties": false
      }
    },
  }
```